# Example of continuous curve $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ for which $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$ which has no point which satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: analysis

Does there exist any continuous curve $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ for which $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$ and for which there is no pair of points $p,q\in f([0,1])$ such that $q-p=0.75$?

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=x + i \sin(2 \pi x ) $$

Comment: If you want a visualization: Consider that we make curves $f$ and $f+0.75$ simultaneously; the latter must pass "above" $1$ (so as not to block $f$) and the former must avoid the latter. So we go up to make $f+0.75$ go over $1$ and dive so that $f$ avoids $f+0.75$. I think similar constructions probably prove that there do not have to points where $f(x)-f(y)=c$ for any $c\neq 0$.

Comment: Nice construction, Meelo. Elegant too.